# Cassandra Java Driver returns deleted columns

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm using Datastax Cassandra Java Driver 2.1.0 to delete a set of rows in the database. My test environment is based on a single node with Cassandra 2.0.7.
I run the delete statement and then checked the result running a query to select the deleted rows.
The problem is that the second query returns the rows, but if I check it via cqlsh, the rows are indeed deleted.

The query trace reports that the rows are marked as tombstoned, so why the select query retrieves the data anyway?
Here is the code for the delete task:

```
Statement query = QueryBuilder.delete().from(QueryBuilder.quote(CF_MESSAGES))
    .where(QueryBuilder.in(CF_MESSAGES_KEY, (Object[]) rowKeyArray));       
session.execute(query);
```

And here the code for the select:

```
query = QueryBuilder.select().all().from(QueryBuilder.quote(CF_MESSAGES))
    .where(QueryBuilder.in(CF_MESSAGES_KEY, (Object[]) rowKeyArray))
    .and(QueryBuilder.lte(CF_MESSAGES_COLUMN1, "2:" + Character.MAX_VALUE));
ResultSet queryResult = session.execute(query);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Repair is an anti entropy mechanism that should be run ~weekly or at least more often than your [gc_grace_seconds](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_deletes_c.html) in order to avoid zombie tombstones from coming back. DataStax OpsCenter has a [Repair Service](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/online_help/services/repairServiceHowItWorks.html) that automates this task.

Manually you can run:

```
nodetool repair
```

in one node or

```
nodetool repair -pr
```

in each of your nodes. The -pr option will ensure you only repair a node's primary ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You should try a `nodetool repair`... I had the same issue :
[Cassandra and defuncting connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795901/cassandra-and-defuncting-connection) (see comments)

Answer (score 0):

If your environment is a test environment try reducing the gc_grace_seconds and check if any node was down(you can check with Linux uptime command) when delete happened.